# how can I find the missing integers when given a list of integers that can be repeated C times cannot add up to value V

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

So I am given 3 input values, C, D, and V. Where D is a list of integers and C is the number of times that any element in D can be repeated when summing to at most a value V.

Now what will always be the case is that not every combination of sums in D will equal 1 to V. Therefore, my function has to find the minimum amount of integers to include in D that will satisfy summing to at most V.

In other words, minimum number of integers to insert into D such that all integers from 1 <= x <= V can be represented by a summation of combination of numbers in D, where no number is repeated more than C times

For example,

```
D = [1, 5, 10, 25]

C = 2 

V = 100
```

As you can see, the max value I can get from D and C is:

2(1+5+10+25) = 82 which is less than V = 100.

I solved it manually where I can satisfy every value from 1 to 100 when I include two new integers in D which is 12 and 2.

So my output would be 12 and 2.

Now the way I saw it was to basically cover all single digit values so since I already have 1 and 5 in D where I can repeat their sums 2 times given by C=2, the values I cannot account for are 3, 4, 8, and 9 which can be resolved by introducing 2 into D and likewise for double digits it would be 12 given C and D.

ie.

```
< 3=1+2, 4=2+2 or 2+1+1, 8=5+2+1, 9=5+2+2 or 5+2+1+1 >
```

What becomes obvious now is the fact that computationally it can be extremely expensive for large values of N, especially if I brute force it.

My strategy was this:

1. Find all possible combinations of sums given D and C then put into a list, and lets call it dSums.
2. Create a list ranging from 1 to V ie.

> vList = [i for i in range(1, v+1, 1)]

3. iterate through dSums and remove any value in dSums from vList

so now I have a list of all integers that are missing but the problem is this.

```
If D = [1, 5], C=2 and V=10

vList = [3, 4, 8, 9]
```

I thought I can find the common integer that will satisfy all the values in vList using D and C but I am not sure how to traverse or map the lists in such a way that I ultimately arrive at my desired value which is 2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it that you need to find the minimum number of integers to insert into `D` such that all integers from `1 <= x <= V` can be represented by a summation of combination of numbers in `D`, where no number is repeated more than `C` times? You should also post the limits of each input as well, if you're not happy with the time complexity of your brute force solution.

Comment: yes exactly how u phrased it.  "minimum number of integers to insert into D such that all integers from 1 <= x <= V can be represented by a summation of combination of numbers in D, where no number is repeated more than C times"

Comment: thing is my brute force solution doesnt even work lol

Comment: it breaks down and cries after a certain value V and then my function returns an empty list and then i cry

Comment: You should edit your question to include your first comment, the reply to @wLui155's question. Questions should be self-contained, in part because readers should not be required to read comments to understand what is being asked.

Comment: Isn't `[3, 11]` a solution for your example too?

Comment: yes i think so too. so there might not be a unique solution but 3, 11 and 2, 12 either or would be sufficient answers